# How to add a form in a modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, modal-dialog, bootbox

I'm doing a modal in jquery. I would to print in my modal a form from symfony. But how can I print the twig in a jquery file?

My twig file:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/test/js/myJquery.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
    {{ form(form) }}
</div>
```

Im jquery I use bootbox (http://bootboxjs.com/), the I add the modal:

```
bootbox.dialog({
                message: 'Le cours aura lien de: '+debut.getHours()+':'+debut.getMinutes()+' à '+fin.getHours()+':'+fin.getMinutes(),
                title: 'Cours individuel',
                buttons: {
                    success: {
                        label: 'oui',
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: Routing.generate('', {}),
                                dataType: "json",
                                beforeSend: function () {

                                },
                                success: function () {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                danger: {
                    label: 'non',
                    className: "btn-danger",
                    callback: function () {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I have to add the twig in th message: xxx

How can I do that?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your modal script is located in twig file - you can render another controller with this code:

```
{{ render(controller('YourBundle:Form:Form')) }}
```

Replace `YourBundle:Form:Form` with your path to controller action.

Comment: read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers

Comment: but in my jquery I cannot enter twig syntax

Comment: then you have two options - move that script from .js file to .twig file, or loading content of that form action with ajax and injecting it into that modal.

Comment: I think that must be a solution. I can access by ajax an create a form, then how can I inject a form via ajax to the javascript file?

Comment: or juste import the result of a twig file in my jquery?